# Proper way to construct a function that takes too long to plot and integrate

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, assignment

Consider the functions `phi[t_]` and `psi[t_]` defined in the code below. These are used as basis functions for interpolation purposes. Consider a "time" variable `T`, a total number of interpolation nodes `n0` and a step `h0`. Consider the values at nodes given by variables `a` and `b`. The required interpolation is defined by the function `q[t_]` defined below as the sum of `a` times `phi` plus `b` times `psi`.

```
phi[t_] := Boole[-1 <= t <= 1] (1 - Abs[t])^2 (1 + 2 Abs[t]);
psi[t_] := Boole[-1 <= t <= 1] t (1 - Abs[t])^2;
T = N@Pi
n0 = 500;
h0 = T/n0;
a = Table[Cos[i*h0], {i, 0, n0}];
b = Table[Sin[i*h0], {i, 0, n0}];
q[t_] = Sum[a[[k + 1]]*phi[t/h0 - k] + h0*b[[k + 1]]*psi[t/h0 - k], {k, 0, n0}];
```

**EDIT NOTE** The above example interpolates the cosine function but the targeted function is not necessarily periodic. `a` and `b` are constructed with `Cos` and `Sin` functions respectively only for example purposes. Values for `a` and `b` come from external computations and are data inputs. Function `q[t]` must interpolate these values using `phi` and `psi` functions defined above, which always require `T`, `n0` and `h0`.

When constructing the interpolated function `q[t_]` in this kind of manner results in operations on `q[t_]` taking way too long. A simple plot for example

```
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[q[t], {t, 0, T}]]
```

takes more than 4 seconds to compute in my machine. Integrating this function with

```
NIntegrate[q[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

sends the message

```
NIntegrate`SymbolicPiecewiseSubdivision::maxpwc: The number of piecewise regions has exceeded the maximum value specified by the option MaxPiecewiseCases -> 100. The integration will continue with no piecewise subdivision.
```

I can get around the integration issue by reducing the number of interpolation nodes to no more than 200, however, this begs the question of whether or not I am doing this the right way. **Is there a better way to construct the `q[t_]` function?**

Note that I cannot define `q[t_]` in the "set delayed" way because my `a` and `b` coefficients are constantly changing to approach other functions, and I need to store every interpolated function separately.

Comment: `Q[t_] = Sum[
   Cos[(k + 1)*h0]*phi[t/h0 - k] + 
    h0*Sin[(k + 1)*h0]*phi[t/h0 - k], {k, 0, n0}];
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[Q[t], {t, 0, T}]]`

Comment: @cvgmt Your solution indeed reduces the time to Plot. However, here you are directly using `Cos` and `Sin` Mathematica functions which were used to define coefficients `a` and `b` only as an example. As I mention at the end of my query, these coefficients are variable and I often not know how they are constructed...

Comment: Meclassic, you can take inspiration or lesson from @cvgmt’s answer in that it shows instead how to use directly the functions for a and b in the `Sum` that may offer better performance, rather than listing them out & calling their corresponding parts from the `Sum` which costs the need to store the list before calling it. Can you, please, clarify further other functions you might use for `a` and `b`? And if you will always subdivide the function using periodic terms set like `T`, `n0`, and `h0`?

Comment: @CATrevillian I have added some further clarifications to my question. `a` and `b` are input data previously stored in lists. The targeted function for interpolation is not necessarily periodic.

Comment: Ah, my suggestion involves directly callable functions to avoid what I think may be a slowdown via the creation, storing, & subsequent calling of lists of data. However I do notice now that your `phi` & `psi` may benefit from memoization or perhaps using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

Comment: On my machine the plot takes 3.1. seconds. You can force the large sum in q[t] into a piecewise function by defining q1[t_]= q[t]//Simplify. With the new function q1 the plot time  is reduced to 0.7 seconds.